# Why my function returns int without sum of 1, or it sums random number

Tags: javascript, steam

I'm trying to convert Steam ID 32bit to Steam ID 64bit.

My javascript function is not working right but same function in python works fine. Python function is copied from [How can I get a steamid 64 from a steamID in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36463885/18073076)

```
function steamidTo64(steamid) {
    let steam64id = 76561197960265728; // Valve's magic constant
    let id_split = steamid.split(":");
    steam64id += parseInt(id_split[2]) * 2;
    if (id_split[1] == "1") {
        steam64id += 1;
    }
    return steam64id;
}
```

Using input of `STEAM_1:1:191000236` function should return `76561198342266201`, but instead it returns `76561198342266200`

Using input of `STEAM_1:1:3645504` function should return `76561197967556737`, but it returns `76561197967556740`

Using input of `STEAM_0:0:570629725` function should return `76561199101525178`, but it returns `76561199101525180`

Comment: Numeric literals with absolute values equal to 2^53 or greater are too large to be represented accurately as integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) since `76561197960265728` is greater than `9007199254740992` (1 digit longer), and so arithmetic operations on this number are inaccurate and can lead to incorrect results.

```js
function steamidTo64(steamid) {
    let steam64id = 76561197960265728n;
    
    const id_split = steamid.split(":");

    steam64id += BigInt(id_split[2]) * 2n;

    if (id_split[1] === "1") steam64id += 1n;

    return steam64id;
}

// Result is BigInt
console.log(steamidTo64("STEAM_1:1:191000236").toString());
```